# Оптимизация кода перебора массива объектов

Tags: javascript

помогите переписать код что бы он выглядел более логичным и понятным, или подскажите каким методом это можно сделать. Логика кода такова:

Если есть объект с `orderStatus: 'ACCEPTED'` то `activeOrder` должен принять этот объект, если есть `orderStatus: 'ACCEPTED' && orderStatus: 'WAITING'`, то приоритетней будет объект `orderStatus: 'ACCEPTED'`, если нету `orderStatus: 'ACCEPTED'` но есть `orderStatus: 'WAITING'` забрать объект с `orderStatus: 'WAITING'`. Если же ничего из этого в массиве объектов нету то оставить `activeOrder = false`.

```js
let order = [{
    orderStatus: 'ACCEPTED'
  },
  {
    orderStatus: 'WAITING'
  },
  {
    orderStatus: 'INCOMPLETE'
  },
];

let activeOrder = false,
  accepted = false,
  waiting = false;

order.forEach((value) => {
  if (value.orderStatus === 'ACCEPTED') {
    accepted = value;
  }
  if (value.orderStatus === 'WAITING') {
    waiting = value;
  }
})

if (accepted !== false && waiting !== false || waiting === false) {
  activeOrder = accepted;
}
if (accepted === false && waiting !== false) {
  activeOrder = waiting;
}
if (accepted === false && waiting === false) {
  activeOrder = false;
}

console.log(activeOrder)
```

Comment: В логику влезать не буду, скажу только, что переменная `accepted`, которая то `Boolean`, то `Object`, - это, на мой взгляд, уже не есть хорошо и усложняет восприятие кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
activeOrder = accepted;
if (!activeOrder) 
  activeOrder = waiting;
```

или

```
activeOrder = accepted || waiting;
```

> без переменных `accepted` и `waiting`

```
var activeOrder = false;
order.forEach((value) => {
  if (!activeOrder) {
    if (value.orderStatus === 'ACCEPTED' || value.orderStatus === 'WAITING')
      activeOrder = value;
  } else if (activeOrder.orderStatus !== 'ACCEPTED') {
    if (value.orderStatus === 'ACCEPTED')
      activeOrder = value;
  }
});
```

или (останавливается, как только найден первый `'ACCEPTED'`)

```
var activeOrder = false;
order.some((value) => {
  if (!activeOrder) {
    if (value.orderStatus === 'ACCEPTED' || value.orderStatus === 'WAITING')
      activeOrder = value;
  } else if (activeOrder.orderStatus !== 'ACCEPTED') {
    if (value.orderStatus === 'ACCEPTED')
      activeOrder = value;
  }
  return activeOrder && activeOrder.orderStatus === 'ACCEPTED';
});
```

Comment: а можно как то без переменных `accepted` и `waiting` лишь методом обойтись? :)

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативное решение может быть следующим: отсортировать коллекцию order в порядке, при котором сначала идут объекты со статусом `'Accepted'`, затем `'Waiting'` и так далее.

А потом просто взять первый элемент со статусом `'Accepted'` или `'Waiting'`, например с помощью метода [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Пример реализации:

```js
let order = [{
    orderStatus: 'INCOMPLETE'
  },
  {
    orderStatus: 'WAITING'
  },
  {
    orderStatus: 'ACCEPTED'
  }
];

let activeOrder = order.sort((a, b) => {
  var statusA = a.orderStatus == 'ACCEPTED' ? 0 : a.orderStatus == 'WAITING' ? 1 : 2;
  var statusB = b.orderStatus == 'ACCEPTED' ? 0 : b.orderStatus == 'WAITING' ? 1 : 2;
  return statusA - statusB;
}).find(v => v.orderStatus == 'ACCEPTED' || v.orderStatus == 'WAITING') || false;

console.log(activeOrder)
```

И самый простой путь - это обычный [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), который позволяет решить задачу за один проход:

1. если статус проверяемого элемента `Accepted` - то сохраняем и заканчиваем цикл
2. если статус проверяемого элемента `Waiting` - то просто сохраняем и идем дальше

```js
let order = [{
    orderStatus: 'INCOMPLETE'
  },
  {
    orderStatus: 'WAITING'
  },
  {
    orderStatus: 'ACCEPTED'
  }
];

let activeOrder = false;

for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
  if (order[i].orderStatus == 'ACCEPTED') {
    activeOrder = order[i];
    break;
  }
  if (activeOrder.orderStatus != 'WAITING' && order[i].orderStatus == 'WAITING') {
    activeOrder = order[i];
  }
}

console.log(activeOrder)
```

Comment: А какое решение будет самым правильным подходом реализации этой логики на ваш взгляд? :)

Comment: @Puvvl, правильное - это то, которое выполняет поставленную задачу. Приведенные все выполняют.

Comment: какой бы вы метод использовали для данной задачи? :)

Comment: @Puvvl, обычно чем проще тем лучше.